# Problem with content type permission

Tags: nodes, users

I have a content type called: **Activity**. Then I have a role called: **Gestor**
In /`admin/people/permissions` I make sure I checked (for the Gestor role):

Activity: Create new content

Activity: Edit own content

Activity: Edit any content

Activity: Delete own content

Activity: Delete any content

Now I login with a Gestor user role and tried to go to /node/add/activity and I get **ACCESS DENY**

The content type has the defaults fields: **body** and **title**.

I already rebuild permission at: `/admin/reports/status/rebuild` but not working...

**UPDATE**
**If I check `Bypass content access control` I get access to fully manage ALL content type**

Comment: Do you have any content access modules (e.g. Content Access) installed or is this a default installation?

Comment: no but... I do have benchwork access enabled...

Comment: I disabled benchwork access and it is working fine. Do you mind moving your comment to an answer so that I can accept it. thanks

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer. What's the exact module name you are referring to. Can't seem to find a benchwork module.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a content access module (e.g. [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access)) installed that's conflicting with the default access settings.

Comment: Questions about questions should be comments, not answers.